# How to append the return of a function to a list and a dictionary in a for loop

Tags: python

I have a function that returns two lists and a dictionary

```
def function():
    mlist1 = []
    mlist2 = []
    mdict = dict()
    return mlist1, mlist2, mdict
```

I run this function in a for loop and unpack the return of the function to x,y, and z

```
for i in range(10):
    x,y,z = function()
```

the problem with the code this way is that x,y, and z get a new value with each iteration.

I want instead to append the output of function() to x,y, and z with each iteration, what is the most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: So why not declaring x,y,z outside the block and append the results of your function directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `function` will return more than just empty lists and dicts. If it should actually just return 10 empty lists and/or dicts, have a look at [ironl1111's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73866591/1617563).

I'd say the most comprehensible way is to assign all values separately.

```py
x = []
y = []
z = {}
# ...
for i in range(10):
    tmp_x, tmp_y, tmp_z = function()
    x.extend(tmp_x)
    y.extend(tmp_y)
    z.update(tmp_z)
```

If you want to keep it short you could use `zip` and pass  `extend` for lists and `update` for dicts. Both update their object in place.

```py
def function():
    mlist1 = [1]
    mlist2 = [2]
    mdict = dict(foo="bar")
    return mlist1, mlist2, mdict

x = []
y = []
z = {}
for i in range(10):
    for value, func in zip(function(), [x.extend, y.extend, z.update]):
        func(value)

print(x)  # [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
print(y)  # [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
print(z)  # {'foo': 'bar'}
```

But the saved lines are in my opinion neglectable. It will cost you or someone else in the future more time to understand what's going on than it saves to write the code. Performance-wise there is most like no gain as well.

Comment: Although this might technically be correct I wouldn't call this solution "pythonic" because it violates the zen of python: "Explicit is better than implicit." , "Simple is better than complex.", "Readability counts.". This is too smart :]

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    # you could
    # 
    # 1.
    # x = [[] for _ in range(10)]

    # 2. 
    # x = []
    # for _ in range(10):
    #   x.append([]) 

    # 3. 
    # i = 0
    # x = []
    # while i < 10:
    #   x.append([])
    #   i += 1

    # they are all valid but you should use the first way or this way

    x = [[]] * 10 
    y = [[]] * 10

    z = {}
    for i in range(10):
        z[i] = {}

    return x, y, z
```